# Array ints and replace the order of number I write

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I try Start the console and after i write 5 numbers is do exsepsion what wrong in code

what the console do is after I write 5 number for example 7,4,9,5,1 ---> 1,5,9,4,7

this what I wrote

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

         int[] numbers = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length ; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("");

            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            int x = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.Length - i - 1];
            numbers[numbers.Length - i - 1] = x;
        }



        Console.Read();
```

Comment: What exsepsion do you get?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Index Out Of Range Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed two things. First - in order to swap two array items, you need to store item somewhere. Otherwise you just replace one item with other. Second - arrays have indexes from `0` to `Length - 1`. So you need to subtract 1 from second item index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length / 2; i++)
{
    int x = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.Length - i - 1];
    numbers[numbers.Length - i - 1] = x;
}
```

Comment: I wrote it and is dosn't work yet

Comment: I don't know what you wrote, but you definitely didn't write my code

Comment: i edit the code and its not working yet

Comment: Have you tried copy-pasting it without editing?